# Read in excel from column AF and onwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

How could I read an Excel file from column AF and onwards? I don't know the last column letter name and the file is too large to constantly keep checking.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"Documents\file.xlsx", usecols="AF:")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't write it directly in `read_excel` function so we can only look for other possible options.

For the moment we could write 'AF:XFD' because 'XFD' is the last column in excel, but it returns information that it will be depracated soon and start returning ParseError, so it's not recommended.

You can use other libraries to find the last column, but it doesn't work too fast - excel file is read, then we check last column and after that we create a dataframe.

If I had such problem I would do everything in Pandas, by adding `.iloc` at the end. We know that 'AF' is 32th column in excel, so:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"Documents\file.xlsx").iloc[:, 32:]
```

It will return all columns from 'AF' till the end without having a noticeable impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xlwings` library to determine the last column in which there is data and then replace it in your code line.

```py
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App(visible = False)
book = app.books.open(r"Documents\file.xlsx")
sheet = xw.Book(r"Documents\file.xlsx").sheets[0]

app.quit()

colNum = sheet.range('AF1').current_region.last_cell.column

df = pd.read_excel(r"Documents\file.xlsx", usecols = list(range(32, colNum, 1)))
```

where 32 corresponds to the column number for AF.