# python - pandas - parse excel columns from start column until empty column

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I am trying to parse an excel using pandas.
I want to parse 1 excel row (e.g first row) starting from a fixed column in the excel (e.g. column "F") and until the last non-empty column.

Until now the last non-empty column was "M" so I used a fixed number for the end like this:

`pd.read_excel(excel_file,"header": None,"nrows": 1, usecols="F:M")`

| - | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | col_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E | FIRST_COL | col_G | col_H | col_I | col_J | col_K | col_L | LAST_COL |

The numbers of columns can grow to the right, and I still want to parse the added columns. The starting column is fixed though.

I tried to look in [panda's `usecols` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
Also I saw that you can use `usecols` with names, but I don't have any knowledge about the name of the last column or any column in this excel.
I can modify the excel though, e.g. to sign the with a special value the column after the last one to parse (if needed), but I don't know how to parse the excel even with that addition.

```
pandas==1.3.4
Python 3.7.5
Windows 10
Excel 2019
```

Comment: can you share your excel file please

Comment: I modified the question and added an example excel

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906584/read-in-excel-from-column-af-and-onwards) I solved it by slicing the parsed excel right after reading it.

```
HEADER_START_COLUMN = str.lower("F")
ASCII_OF_A_LETTER = 96
HEADER_START_COLUMN_INT = ord(HEADER_START_COLUMN) - ASCII_OF_A_LETTER
pd_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_file,"header": None,"nrows": 1).iloc[:, HEADER_START_COLUMN_INT:]
```